# How to put form inputs on the same line

Tags: html, asp.net, blazor-server-side

How to format form inputs to two per line. I am using Asp.net Blazor. Ideally I would like to place this form inside a div with a gray background color; placing 2 input boxes per line.

```
            <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.PointOfContact" placeholder="Point of Contact" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 font-weight-bold bm-container" style="width:auto">

            <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.ReqWhse" placeholder="Requesting Warehouse" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 font-weight-bold bm-container" style="width:auto">

            <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.FutureReplnWhse" placeholder="Future Replenishmnet Warehouse" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 font-weight-bold bm-container" style="width:auto">

            <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.ProductKey_AltCode" placeholder="Product Key or Alt Key" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 font-weight-bold bm-container" style="width:auto">

            <InputDate class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.StartDate" placeholder="Start Date" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 font-weight-bold bm-container" style="width:auto">

            <InputDate class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.EndDate" placeholder="End Date" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>




</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the inputs in rows
and wrap all the rows in a container utilizing bootstrap.

```
<div class="form-group" style="width:800px; height:500px;text-align:center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <InputText class=" form-control col-sm" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.PointOfContact" placeholder="Point of Contact" />
                &nbsp;
                <InputText class=" form-control col-sm" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.ReqWhse" placeholder="Requesting Warehouse" />
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            &nbsp;

            <div class="row">

                <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.FutureReplnWhse" placeholder="Future Replenishmnet Warehouse" />
                &nbsp;
                <InputText class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.ProductKey_AltCode" placeholder="Product Key or Alt Key" />
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div class="row">

                <InputDate class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.StartDate" placeholder="Start Date" />
                &nbsp;
                <InputDate class="form-control col-3" @bind-Value="_FormAModel.EndDate" placeholder="End Date" />
                &nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```